# Rest API - Import JSON file with products to Drupal 8 and create product nodes with that data

Tags: php, json, api, drupal, drupal-8

For a website I have to import products with a Rest API to a Drupal 8 webshop. Here is the documentation of the API: https://www.floraathome.nl/api-documentatie/v1/

I succesfully got the data from all products using:

```
https://api.floraathome.nl/v1/products/get?apitoken=[MY_TOKE]&type=json
```

I also succeeded printing out some data from it in a PHP file:

```
<?php 

$url = 'https://api.floraathome.nl/v1/products/get?apitoken=[MY_TOKE]&type=json';
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$retVal = json_decode($json, TRUE);

foreach($retVal['data'] as $retV){
    echo $retV['dutchname']."<br>";
    echo $retV['purchaseprice']."<br>";
    echo $retV['promotionaltext']."<br><br>";
}
```

I have no experience with API's or anything like it. But now I would like to be able to import the data from the API into Drupal 8, as products.

What would be my best solution to approach this?

Thanks in advance,

Mike

Comment: 1. Get a sample CSV of product  in drupal 8. 2. Now create same kind of CSV with your current data using  PHP `csv` functions

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it, I hope it works for you.

For store creation:

```
<?php
// The store type. Default is 'online'.
$type = 'online';

// The user id the store belongs to.
$uid = 1;

// The store's name.
$name = 'My Store';

// Store's email address.
$mail = 'admin@example.com';

// The country code.
$country = 'US';

// The store's address.
$address = [
  'country_code' => $country,
  'address_line1' => '123 Street Drive',
  'locality' => 'Beverly Hills',
  'administrative_area' => 'CA',
  'postal_code' => '90210',
];

// The currency code.
$currency = 'USD';

// If needed, this will import the currency.
$currency_importer = \Drupal::service('commerce_price.currency_importer');
$currency_importer->import($currency);

$store = \Drupal\commerce_store\Entity\Store::create([
  'type' => $type,
  'uid' => $uid,
  'name' => $name,
  'mail' => $mail,
  'address' => $address,
  'default_currency' => $currency,
  'billing_countries' => [
    $country,
  ],
]);

// If needed, this sets the store as the default store.
$store_storage = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('commerce_store');
$store_storage->markAsDefault($store);

// Finally, save the store.
$store->save();
```

For variation (indicated by `$variation` do something like

```
<?php
$price = new \Drupal\commerce_price\Price('24.99', 'USD');

$variation = ProductVariation::create([
  'type' => 'default', // The default variation type is 'default'.
  'sku' => 'test-product-01', // The variation sku.
  'status' => 1, // The product status. 0 for disabled, 1 for enabled.
  'price' => $price,
]);
$variation->save();
```

Finally, for the product:

```
<?php
use \Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\Product;
use \Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\ProductVariation;

$req=\Drupal::httpClient()->get("https://api.floraathome.nl/v1/products/get?apitoken=[MY_TOKE]&type=json");
$res=json_decode($req);
foreach($res['data'] as $r) {
  $product = Product::create(['type' => 'default', 'variations' => $variation, 'stores' => $sid]);
  $product->set('title', $r['dutchname'];
  ...
  ...
  ...
```

$product->save();
    }

I hope you get the idea.

Note: Needless to say, I had to make variables/values up as I don't have access to the API.